# Problema con la invocación de un método desde una biblioteca de clases en Vb Net (dll)

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

Tengo mi proyecto principal y usando la reflexión logré hacer el llamado de un método de otra biblioteca de clases (dll), pero ésta a pesar de que si entra a leer las instrucciones(debug) y no da errores en tiempo de ejecución, no realiza ninguna acción.

Sí, está referenciada correctamente.

Esta es la forma en como ejecuto un método (que además, sí, es público) que se encuentra en otra librería.

```
        Dim magicType As Type = _ensamblador.GetType(GetNamespacesInAssembly(_ensamblador) & "." & _ultimoControl.Name.ToString)
        Dim magicConstructor As ConstructorInfo = magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
        Dim magicClassObject As Object = magicConstructor.Invoke(New Object() {})
        Dim magicMethod As MethodInfo = magicType.GetMethod("NombreDelMétodo")
        magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, New Object() {})
```

Funciona correctamente, pero en:

```
Public Sub NombreDelMétodo()
   _common.CleanAllControls(gbx_sistema)
   _common.CleanAllControls(gbx_modulos)
   _common.CleanAllControls(gbx_submodulos)
   _common.CleanAllControls(gbx_transferir)
   InitialConfig()
   'Refresh()
End Sub
```

Cuando el sistema está en ejecución, no logro ver los cambios en tiempo real. Intenté con llamar el método Refresh a mi User Control, al panel donde están cargados todos los controles de formulario pero nada. Alguna idea de que pudiera estar haciéndome falta?, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos encontré la solución, pues me di cuenta que no estaba haciendo uso de la misma instancia, y como es que lo sé, bueno porque me obligué a imprimir en un mensaje con el ID de la instancia (algo como el PID) y me di cuenta de que eran procesos totalmente diferentes jaja, entonces lo que hice pues únicamente sustituir la variable ensamblado 
justo cuando creo la instancia. El código sería el siguiente:

Optimicé el código quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
If _tipoEnsamblado IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim methodInfo As MethodInfo = _tipoEnsamblado.GetMethod("Ejemplo")

            If methodInfo IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim result As Object = Nothing
                Dim parameters As ParameterInfo() = methodInfo.GetParameters()                

                If parameters.Length = 0 Then
                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(_UserControl, Nothing)
                Else
                    Dim parametersArray As Object() = New Object() {"LosParametros"}
                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray)
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Incluso metí (lo que ya se aprende cuando usar POO) en caso de que el método use parámetros.

Funciona correctamente, si alguien tiene alguna duda con mucho gusto ayudo. Saludos